# Why are the Mamluk Sultans of Delhi termed as being of Turkish origin?

Tags: middle-ages, india, afghanistan

They should have instead be termed as being of Afghan origin and not Turkish origin since their founder Qutb-Ud-Din Aibek was the slave of Muhammad Ghori who was the Sultan of Ghur in Afghanistan.

Comment: You might be confused by the fact that the Turks haven't always lived in Turkey. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkic_migration and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkic_peoples#/media/File:Carte_peuples_turcs.png

Comment: It is also important to note the difference between [*Turkic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkic_languages) and [*Turkish*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_language). Either applying to a people or to a language.

Answer (score 6):

But even [Mu'izz ad-Din Muhammad Ghori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_of_Ghor)  acknowledged the [slaves origin as Turkish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_of_Ghor#Succession).

> Mu'izz had no offspring, but he treated his Turkic slaves as his sons,
>   who were trained both as soldiers and administrators

and from the [Concise History of Islam](https://books.google.com/books?id=eACqCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA191&lpg=PA191&dq=my%20Turkish%20slaves%20who%20will%20be%20the%20heirs%20of%20my%20dominions&source=bl&ots=oyhnwfbJlp&sig=zxYm4R6xwDYBPOWAbeBEZmjSNpQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfk46um5nPAhVM4YMKHXurCCoQ6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> "Other monarchs may have one son, or two sons; I have thousands of
>   sons, *my Turkish slaves* who will be the heirs of my dominions, and
>   who, after me, will take care to preserve my name in the Khuṭbah
>   (Friday sermon) throughout these territories."

and back to wikipedia:

> Mu'izz's prediction proved true. After his assassination, his Empire
>   was divided amongst his slaves. Most notably: [Qutbu l-Din Aibak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qutb_al-Din_Aibak) became
>   ruler of Delhi in 1206, establishing the Sultanate of Delhi, which
>   marked the start of the Slave dynasty.[30]